# Is it possible to travel anywhere on Eurail-valid lines without reserving a seat or paying fees?

Tags: eurail

I'm wondering if I buy a Eurail Continuous Global pass but don't mind traveling on slow trains and transferring a lot, I can avoid paying any fees or making any advance registrations...i.e. just "hop on".

I've read that although almost all high-speed and otherwise desirable train services offered by a Eurail pass require an additional fee for seat reservations, but that all regional short-distance trains don't require additional fees.

Here's a Eurail map: http://www.eurail.com/sites/eurail.com/files/documents/eurail_railway_map_2014.pdf
Are the RED lines possible to travel using a Eurail pass without additional fees or tickets?

What else might there be additional fees or advance reservation requirements for? Traveling at certain times of day? Traveling high-traffic commuter routes during rush hour?

Comment: The Eurail web site has a very extensive list of trains, on which you have to pay an additional fee for mandatory reservations (Reservation Guide). There are different rules from country to country. Do you have a specific question not covered by what you can find in this list?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the eurail site itself for all that information - see [here](http://www.eurail.com/trains-europe/regional-trains#reservations) for information on reservation on regional trains; in short: there's very little exceptions to the rule that regional trains don't require reservation. [Here](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/reservation-guide/reservation-fees/domestic-train-reservation-fees) is a list (by country) of where reservation is needed or optional and what the cost would be.

There's also a feature to avoid trains that require reservation in any search you make on the site - [see here for explanation](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/guide-eurail-train-reservations/can-i-avoid-trains-reservations).

Especially in France required reservations are very common - that's why eurail has a [page on this very issue](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/guide-eurail-train-reservations/limited-seats-french-trains) and [gives alternative routes](http://www.eurail.com/plan-your-trip/guide-eurail-train-reservations/alternative-routes-french-trains) for some of the most popular routes involving France.